# How to toggle between 2 Desktops with one hotkey in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys, multiple-desktop

I want to have one hotkey to do that.
at the moment I have to press Win+Ctrl+ Left/Right
Is it possible to press one combination to get from desktop 1 to desktop 2 and the other way around?

Comment: If you are using a laptop with a touchpad that supports multi-touch gestures, using a three-finger-swipe left or right allows you to cycle desktops.

Comment: My bad. It's four fingers, at least on my Inspiron 7000 series.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup a Macro if you are using a Macro-Compatible Keyboard :)

But if you dont you can use [AutoHotkey](http://ahkscript.org/)

You can find several Tutorials for AutoHotkey on Google. I dont know myself a way to just have one combination.

Comment: I have macro keys on my keyboard, but i only want to use one key for it

Comment: That wont be easy to do. The problem is that Windows is not supporting one Key for switching between VD's cause you can just create more then one and yeah. I can only recommend to set two macro-keys.